# Display VF Pie chart as Contact specific

Tags: apex, visualforce-charting

I have created a VF Pie chart which displays data of an object (Position__c). This object has a lookup to Contact. I want pie chart to be contact specific i.e whenever I select a Contact, data related to that specific contact should be visible on Pie chart. Attaching the code.

My Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Client">                
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedName}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ContactList}"/> 
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowTransactions}" rerender="AccountSummarypageBlock,PositionPie"/>             
           </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageblockSection> 
       </apex:pageBlock>  

<apex:outputPanel id="AccountSummarypageBlock" style="width:100%">                        
                    <apex:pageBlock id="AccountSummary" tabStyle="Position__c">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Summary Details">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conwrpList}" var="v" id="con">                            
                        <apex:column value="{!v.transRec.Category__c}" width="10%" />
                        <apex:column value="{!v.transRec.Quantity__c}" width="20%"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!v.transRec.CMP__c}" width="20%"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!v.transRec.Amount_New__c}"width="20%"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!v.transRec.Gain_Loss__c}" width="20%"/>                          
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </apex:pageBlock>
                    </apex:outputPanel>                  
           <!-- New Pie Chart-->            
           <apex:outputPanel id="PositionPie" style="width:100%"> 
          <apex:pageBlock id="PositionData" title="Portfolio Mix">              
    <apex:chart height="250" width="350" data="{!PieData}" > 
        <apex:pieSeries tips="true" dataField="pdata" labelField="name"/> 
        <apex:legend position="right"/>
    </apex:chart>        
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

My Controller:

```
 Public List<Transaction__c > TransactionList{get;set;}  
Public List<Position__c> PositionList{get;set;} 
Public List<ContactWrapper> conwrpList{get;set;}
 Public String selectedName {get;set;}

 Public List<SelectOption> getContactList(){
List<SelectOption>ContactList = new List<SelectOption>();
    ContactList.add(new SelectOption('','------------select-----------'));
    List<Contact>conList = [select Id,Name, Group__c  from Contact where Group__c='Client'];
    for(Contact a:conList){
        ContactList.add(new SelectOption(a.id,a.name));
        System.debug('=====ContactList=====' +ContactList);
    }
    return ContactList;
}

Public PageReference ShowTransactions(){
    TransactionList = [select name, Account__c, Amount__c, Category__c,Amount_New__c, Client_ID__c, CMP__c, Gain_Loss__c, Order_Type__c, Product__c, Product_Code__c, Product__r.Price__c, Quantity__c, Transaction_Date__c, Yield__c from Transaction__c where Client_ID__c =:SelectedName];
 conwrpList = new List<ContactWrapper>();
    for(Transaction__c  w :TransactionList){
    conwrpList.add(new ContactWrapper(false,w));
  }
     return null;
 }

 public class ContactWrapper{
    public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
    public Transaction__c  transRec {get;set;}
    public ContactWrapper(Boolean isSelected, Transaction__c  transRec){
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
    this.transRec = transRec;
    }
}   

  //Pie Chart

public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() 
{  
    List<PieWedgeData> pdat = new List<PieWedgeData>();
    //List<Position__c> memb = new List<Position__c>();  
    List<Position__c> post = [SELECT ID, Product_New__c, Product__c, Quantity__c, Contact__c FROM Position__c];
    //String sql = 'SELECT Name, Product__c, Quantity__c FROM Position__c';
    //memb = Database.Query(sql);
    for(Position__c temp : post)
    {     
        //pdata.add(new PieWedgeData('State', 29));
        //System.debug('=====Product__c=====' +temp.Product__c);
        if(temp.Product_New__c !=null && temp.Quantity__c !=null)
        {
            pdat.add(new PieWedgeData(temp.Product_New__c, temp.Quantity__c));
        }
    }
    //pdata.add(new PieWedgeData('State', 29));
    //pdata.add(new PieWedgeData('Country', 25));
   // pdat.add(new PieWedgeData('Continent', 7));
    return pdat;  
} 

// Wrapper class  
public class PieWedgeData 
{  
    public String name { get; set; }  
    public Decimal pdata { get; set; }  

    public PieWedgeData(String name, Decimal pdata) 
    {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.pdata = pdata;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code appears to set the Contact ID in a field called `selectedName` (that ought to be renamed).

So if `Position__c.Contact__c` is the Contact ID, this should filter your pie chart data correctly when you re-render `PositionPie`:

```
List<Position__c> post = [
        SELECT ID, Product_New__c, Product__c, Quantity__c, Contact__c
        FROM Position__c
        WHERE Contact__c = :selectedName
        ];
```

Comment: I did this earlier but it didn't worked at that time. However I modified the code again and added "WHERE" clause and this time it worked. Thanks alot....